# Can't get input from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get value of input from DOM, but I get an

```
error caught ReferenceError: inputEmail is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.butn (
```

Here is JS code:

```
class Formapp {
  constructor(fullname, email, job) {
    this.inputName = document.querySelector("#inputName");
    this.inputEmail = document.querySelector("#Email");
    this.inputJob = document.querySelector("#Job");
    this.tbody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
    this.btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    this.data = []

    this.fullname = fullName
    this.email = email
    this.job = job
  }
  
  butn() {
    this.fullname = +inputName.value;
    this.email = +inputEmail.value;
    this.job = +inputJob.value
    this.data.push(fullName, email, job)
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log(this.inputEmail);

    this.tbody.innerHTML = this.data ? .map(function(item, index) {
      return `        <tr class="table-light ">
            <td class="table-light">${index+1}${item.fullName}</td>
            <td class="table-light">${item.email}</td>
            <td class="table-light">${item.job}</td>
          </tr>
        `
    }).join("")

    this.inputName.value = ""
    this.inputEmail.value = ""
    this.inputJob.value = ""

  }

  
}
var person1 = new Formapp("salam", 'k@k.com', 'asdasd')
btn.onclick = person1.butn
```

On HTML side everything looks ok. I am having problem with manipulating DOM from inside of class. I have other projects with constructor function and I am doing exactly the thing.
When use console.log(this.inputEmail) right before butn() function, console sees it. But inside butn function I can't call it.

Comment: You're using `inputEmail.value`. It should be `this.inputEmail.value`.

Comment: I did that too. Didn;t help. On that case it gives me this error:  caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.butn (

Comment: First, fix the problem mentioned by Michael M. Then, use `btn.onclick = person1.butn.bind(person1)`

Comment: I did and it helped. But  now data gives me undefined.

Comment: You are adding the input values to the array. Then in `map()` you are trying to read properties `fullName` etc. from those input values, but strings (nor numbers) have those properties.

Comment: You still need to access with `this.`: `this.data.push(this.fullname, this.email, this.job)`